# JOOQ slow code generation

Tags: java, sql, jooq

Are there any parameters, which can turn on/off execution of next query during jooq code generation?

```
SELECT "SYS"."ALL_OBJECTS"."OWNER",
     "SYS"."ALL_OBJECTS"."OBJECT_NAME",
     "SYS"."ALL_OBJECTS"."OBJECT_ID",
     "SYS"."ALL_PROCEDURES"."AGGREGATE"
FROM "SYS"."ALL_OBJECTS"
     LEFT OUTER JOIN "SYS"."ALL_PROCEDURES"
        ON (    "SYS"."ALL_OBJECTS"."OWNER" =
                   "SYS"."ALL_PROCEDURES"."OWNER"
            AND "SYS"."ALL_OBJECTS"."OBJECT_NAME" =
                   "SYS"."ALL_PROCEDURES"."OBJECT_NAME")
WHERE (    UPPER ("SYS"."ALL_OBJECTS"."OWNER") IN ( 'MYSCHEMA')
      AND "SYS"."ALL_OBJECTS"."OBJECT_TYPE" IN ( 'FUNCTION', 'PROCEDURE'))
ORDER BY "SYS"."ALL_OBJECTS"."OWNER" ASC,
     "SYS"."ALL_OBJECTS"."OBJECT_NAME" ASC,
     "SYS"."ALL_OBJECTS"."OBJECT_ID" ASC
```

On database with large number of schemas and objects it tooks about one hour to be executed

Comment: Hmm, OK, that `UPPER(OWNER)` expression in there probably prevents using a useful index on the column... We'll look into it. What Oracle database version are you using, and what jOOQ version? For this particular query, you could turn off the `<includeRoutines/>` and `<includePackages/>` flags in the `<database/>` configuration: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-include-object-types

Comment: Oracle 11.2.0.4, JOOQ 3.7.2. Seems that flags, you mentioned, are for JOOQ 3.9?

Comment: Hmm, the flags were added in jOOQ 3.8, but the documentation currently doesn't reflect that. A workaround would be to override the `JavaGenerator` and its `generatePackages()` and `generateRoutines()` methods to be empty. I'll provide an answer with this information, soon

Comment: One more question (if you're allowed to publish this info): What does this query yield for you (otherwise, a PM would do as well)? `SELECT object_type, count(*) FROM all_objects GROUP BY object_type ORDER BY object_type;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One major issue with the query run by jOOQ is the `UPPER(OWNER)` expression. This was introduced with jOOQ 2.4 ([#1418](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/1418)) to prevent misconfigurations where users accidentally use lower case schema names. The feature was based on an erroneous assumption that case-sensitive users are impossible. They are certainly possible (even if rare), so #1418 was wrong. I've created two issues for this problem:

- [#5989](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5989): Fix the performance issue by avoiding functions on the `OWNER` column
- [#5990](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5990): Re-enact case-sensitive schema names

In the meantime, you have some possible workarounds:

#### Pre jOOQ 3.8

You can always override the `JavaGenerator` from jooq-codegen and re-implement some methods including `generatePackages()` and `generateRoutines()` to be empty. This way, the relevant code will not be executed at all.

Of course, this means you won't get any generated packages and routines.

#### Post jOOQ 3.8

There is a new configuration option where you can do the same as above configuratively:

```xml
<configuration>
  <generator>
    <database>
      <includeRoutines>false</includeRoutines>
      <includePackages>false</includePackages>
      ...
```

See also:
https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-include-object-types

Comment: Thank you, Lukas! Now it takes 11 min for whole generation. But seems that there are another queries that used UPPER for schema name

Comment: @DmitryAgibov: Yes indeed #5989 will fix this for jOOQ 3.9.2 and 3.8.8, whereas #5990 will fix this for 3.10. Some further workarounds might include to provide the jOOQ code generator with a custom JDBC Connection, which regex-replaces all `UPPER\((.*?)\)` expressions by `$1` in jooq-meta queries. I'm not sure if that's doable for you? Otherwise, feel free to report other slow queries, and I'll look at them separately. Perhaps there's a low hanging fruit...